# Flutter TypeAheadField not showing results

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, wikipedia-api

I am having some trouble displaying data from API ( `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/search/title?q=bojack&limit=5` )

The API works on PostMan.
I am using this plugin  `https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead`

###### This is my Search page

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
    return  Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body:  Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

        child:TypeAheadField(
          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
            controller: _controller,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
            autofocus: true,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder()
            )
          ),
          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
            
            if (pattern != null && pattern.length > 0) {
              return await BackendService.getSuggestions(pattern);
            } else {
              return [];
            }
          },
          itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              title: Text('\$${suggestion}'),
            );
          },
          onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
            Get.back();
          },

        )
      )
    );
  }
```

##### This is the Backend Class Service

```
class BackendService {
  
  static Future<Iterable<Object?>> getSuggestions(query) async {
    
    var res = await CallApi().wikipediaGet('search/title?q=$query&limit=5');

    var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print(data.runtimeType);

    return data;
    
  }
}
```

This is what I see on the emulator
[image](https://i.ibb.co/s6QrPv0/Error-Screen.png)

##### How can I show/fetch (new) results on the list when the user type on the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting api response in map and you are returning list from your getSuggestions function so you need to return list of `pages` key from map.

Refactor your backend service code to this

```
class BackendService {
  
  static Future<List<Object>> getSuggestions(query) async {
    
    var res = await CallApi().wikipediaGet('search/title?q=$query&limit=5');

    var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print(data.runtimeType);

    return data['pages'];
    
  }
}
```